# Android: How to track of upgrade stats from a specific version number

Tags: android, statistics, app-update

I have an app that I recently took from 1.0 to 2.0 and have had 7 updates making current version 2.0.7.

In Android Dev console I get daily number of people updating but this stat includes all updates and does not show from which version people are updating most.

I would like to know how many people are updating daily from an old version 1.0 to 2.0.x and NOT from 2.0.6 -> 2.0.7.

Is there anyways to get this stat?

(I do have Google Analytics setup as well)

Comment: You could manually track the number of 1.0 installations every day. This would give you a rough idea how many people updated the app but you wouldn't be able to differentiate between updates and uninstalls.

Comment: Thanks. I get the part about updates but not about uninstalls, how do you mean?

Comment: Say you have 50 installations with version 1.0 today and 45 tomorrow. This means that 5 users either upgraded to a higher version or completely removed the app from their device.